# Changing cgi to Fastcgi

Tags: apache, cgi, fastcgi

How feasible is to change a C/C++ cgi application to Fastcgi? Does this require only change in code? Or will it require a change in the setup of apache server?

What will be the obvious benefits of the change? Is the change from cgi to Fastcgi worth the benefits?

Answer (score 2):

The major benefit of switching to FastCGI is that your application will run continuously in the background, instead of being started for each request. If your app has a lot of initialization, you could see a big speed boost by cutting out that time.

It *will* require reconfiguring Apache, but it's not complex. And it *should* require changing your app, because now there's only one instance per server, not one instance per request. You'll have to decide for yourself if that change is feasible; it really depends on how your code is structured.

Comment: as you said "FastCGI is that your application will run continuously in the background, instead of being started for each request. If your app has a lot of initialization, you could see a big speed boost by cutting out that time." is it similar like Servlet Container ????????????? if no than what are the performance differences??????